# Passing a value from an external table with a single column and row to a function

Tags: sql, hive

I have a file with a single value - 3 which means 3 months.

I have created an external table above that.

```
create external table dim_life_time(life_time int) location......
```

I need to filter out all users whose life_time is less than 3.

```
select *
from users
where start_date > add_months(${current_date}, -life_time)
```

Start date and current date are in this format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Can I pass life time this way?

```
add_months(${current_date}, (select -life_time from db.dim_life_time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from users x
cross join dim_life_time y
where start_date > add_months(${current_date}, 0 - life_time )
```